# Highcharts syntax for responsive options

Tags: highcharts, responsive

The project I work on uses Angular 4 + Highcharts 5.0.14

I want to make a chart responsive. For this purpose I would like to use the API and the defined `responsive` property. But the following piece of code throws an error:

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ title: { text: string; }; subtitle: { text: string; }; yAxis: { title: { text: string; }; }; le...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.   Types of property 'responsive' are incompatible.
        Type '{ rules: { condition: { maxWidth: number; }; chartOptions: { legend: { layout: string; align: str...' is not assignable to type 'ResponsiveOptions[]'.
          Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'rules' does not exist in type 'ResponsiveOptions[]'.
```

Seems that using an array instead of object for the `responsive` property does not produce an error but can not set any other properties inside `chartOptions`:

```
      responsive: [{
          rules: [{
              condition: {
                  maxWidth: 500
              },
              chartOptions: {

            }
          }]
      }]
```

Since I'm new to Angular and Highcharts I can not understand why the error occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Everything is working well. Could you tell me how exactly are you setting the chart options? Maybe it is possible to provide me with minimal working example which shows the problem?
Here is my working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o5yom5yw99